# Ajax POSTS not updating screen content

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, grails, post

So I have a "scenario", made up of lots of "forms" which contain lots of "events" and "data" etc.  To populate all this information I have this in the page to run once the page is finished

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var scenarioID = ${testScenarioInstance.id}
var myData = ${results as JSON}
populateFormData(myData, scenarioID);
});
```

This then calls the functions below (the first calls the second, done like this as I had an issue where as it was ajax the variables in the loop were updating before things were being appended and so everything ended up in the last sub table): -

```
function populateFormData(results, scenarioID) {
    $table = $('#formList')
    for ( var i in results) {
        var formIDX = (results[i]["forms_idx"])
        var formID = (results[i]["form_id"])
        appendSubTable(formIDX, scenarioID, $table, formID);
    }
}
    function appendSubTable(formIDX, scenarioID, $table, formID) {
    var url = "http://localhost:3278/FARTFramework/testScenario/ajaxPopulateSubTables"
    $.post(url, {
        formIDX : formIDX, scenarioID : scenarioID, formID :formID 
    }, function(data) {
        var $subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")
        $subTable.append(data)
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("it failed!")
    });
}
```

This then goes off grabs the data from the controller like so..

```
def ajaxPopulateSubTables(int formIDX, int scenarioID, int formID) {
        def db = new Sql(dataSource)

        String mySQL = "Loads of SQL STUFF"
        def subTableResults = db.rows(mySQL)

        render(template: "subTableEntry", model: [subTableResults:subTableResults, formID:formID, formIDX:formIDX])
    }
```

and fires it at the gsp:

```
    <colgroup>
        <col width="150"/>
        <col width="350"/>
        <col width="350"/>
        <col width="350"/>
    </colgroup>
<g:if test="${subTableResults != null && !subTableResults.isEmpty()}">
    <tr>
        <th>eventIDX</th>
        <th>eventID </th>
        <th>objID</th>
        <th>testVal</th>
    </tr>
</g:if>


<g:each in="${subTableResults}" status = "i" var="item">
    <tr id = ${i} class="${((i) % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}" name="main">
        <td>${item.events_idx}</td>
        <td>${item.type}</td>   
        <td>${item.object_description}</td>
        <td><g:textField id = "testData[${formIDX}:${formID}:${i}]" name="testData[${formIDX}:${formID}:${i}]" value="${item.value}" optionKey="id" /></td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Before then jamming it into the relevant sub table.

The problem is, sometime when I load up a page not all the sub tables are filled out, but if I hit F5 to refresh the page this then seems to fix the issue...  Although not always, sometimes I then get a different section not refreshing :(

I put a println into the controller to see if all the SQLs were being fired off but it always returns all the individual form SQL strings fine...

Looking in firebug all the POSTs are coming back fine but the page just isn't updating...

Any suggestions or ideas as to what might be causing this would be appreciated, I'm at a loss..

I also tried updating my appendSubTable function where the post is to include a fail in case something was failing, but this isn't hit either, have updated code above to show this

Comment: Use some tool like Firebug to see the ajax calls happening. They all return to the browser?

Comment: @SérgioMichels I've got firebug, how do I see if the ajax calls are happening and returning to the browser?

Comment: Worked out how to get this to show.  By the looks of it all the POSTs are returning with data, but the page just doesn't seem to be displaying everything, I can see that when I look at the html within firebug the empty table has nothing in there, but looking at the POSTs I can see it comes back with data :S

Comment: BTW - when I say I worked out how to get this to show I meant the firebug debug stuff not getting all the posts to show on the page...

Comment: It's probably your `function(data)` not handling correctly the data returned.

Comment: Any suggestions for how I could debug this?  Looking at it in firebug all the correct html appears to be getting returned, all within milliseconds, its just not attaching it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly I altered the post function slightly to the below, moving the finding of the table to the beginning of the function rather than within the post itself and that *seems* to have done the trick, although why I'm not sure...   Whether someone can explain why this is or not I'd be interested to know why!

```
function appendSubTable(formIDX, scenarioID, $table, formID) {
    var $subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")
    var url = "http://localhost:3278/FARTFramework/testScenario/ajaxPopulateSubTables"
    $.post(url, {
        formIDX : formIDX, scenarioID : scenarioID, formID :formID 
    }, function(data) {
        $subTable.append(data)
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("fail")
    });
}
```